# GridSearchCV VS CV of the model

Tags: python, performance, validation, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is the difference between using RidgeClassifierCV and
tuning the model after training it

```
classifier = RidgeClassifierCV(alphas=np.logspace(-3, 3, 10), normalize=True)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

AND

```
param_grid = {'alphas': np.logspace(-3, 3, 10)}
grid = GridSearchCV(RidgeClassifier(),param_grid, refit = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RidgeClassifierCV` allows you to perform cross validation and find the best `alpha` with respect to your dataset.

`GridSearchCV` allows you not only to finetune an estimator but the preprocessing steps of a `Pipeline` as well.

From the documentation, The advantage of an `EstimatorCV` such as `RidgeClassifierCV` is that they can take advantage of warm-starting by reusing precomputed results in the previous steps of the cross-validation process. This generally leads to speed improvements.

As a conclusion if you are only trying to finetune a ridge classifier, `RidgeClassifierCV` should be the best choice as it might be faster. However if you are having extra preprocessing steps, it should be better to use `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: One more benefit: the `EstimatorCV`s can provide default hyperparameter search spaces and more tailored introspection (e.g. lasso paths).